# Unable to parse huge XML file of 15 GB using element tree in boto3

Tags: boto3

I am trying to read the content from S3 XML file and trying to split the file using element tree parse.but due to huge volume element tree parse is not happening.

```
Mybucket=s3client.get_object(Bucket=my bucket,Key=FileNm)
XML_data=mybucket[body].read()
Context=ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(XML_data))
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: It's getting killed. This is happening in et parse

Comment: can you include the error log in the question too

Comment: Just saying killed no other error message